# 404 Page Not Found on /Page/2/ on Tag Page

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, tags

Im using this code in my other site which similar theme. All settings are the same even in Admin dashboard. But this one is not working. All content are from custom post type. Am I missing something? maybe a better code?

```
<?php

if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
        $paged = get_query_var('paged');
    } elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {
        $paged = get_query_var('page');
    } else {
        $paged = 1;
    }

$qobj = get_queried_object();
if ( !$qobj )
return;
else

$args = array(
  'post_type' => array('portal'),
  'orderby' => 'id',
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
  'paged' => $paged,
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => $qobj->taxonomy,
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => $qobj->name
    )
  )
);

$random_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ($random_query->have_posts()) :
    while ($random_query->have_posts()) : $random_query->the_post();

?>

<?php //all content ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="the-pagination">
<?php
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'prev_text'          => __(' Previous'),
    'next_text'          => __('Next '),
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $random_query->max_num_pages
) );
?>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. I forgot to add this in my `functions.php`. I will leave the answer here so it may help others.

```
//Tag pagination pages
function wpd_custom_types_on_tag_archives( $query ){
    if( $query->is_tag() && $query->is_main_query() ){
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'portal' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpd_custom_types_on_tag_archives' );
```